# Check if Generic type is list

Tags: java, generics

Giving this Generic response in Java:

```
Response<T> response;
```

How do I check if `T` is instance of `List<?>` (that the response I received is a list) ?

Thanks in advance

Elad

Comment: You can't do that at compile time (unless your code already defines the concrete type in a way that reflection can access this definition) and due to type erasure you only can check whether you got a `List` at runtime (i.e. the raw type). To do this you need to get the value from the response and use `instanceof` or something similar.

Comment: The only way I can think of is for Response class to contain a method like checkIfList(T type) and return true if type instanceof List.